# Sending a zipfile attached to email via Android's Intent fails for GMail

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,Uri.fromParts("mailto:","abc@gmail.com", null));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"<email@example.com>"}); 
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "<Subject here>");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<Body text here>");

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" +     CachedFileProvider.AUTHORITY + "/" +files[0].getName()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email..."));
```

I succeed to attach a plain text file but a zipped file fails with the message

> not possible to attach empty file

in the Gmail client.

Tried to set 
    `Intent.setType("application/zip")` etc.

I left out the parcable code included to allow sending cached files

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, valid file unzipping ok and file size small etc.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

```
Uri a = Uri.fromFile(Zipfile);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, a);
```

Simpy adding a zipped file from cache the extra parcel handling not needed.